# PHP - reset password program

Tags: php

I am making a php program for users to reset their password if they forget it and I am wondering how I should send the user the url to their email to click. I thought about encrypting their user id and decrypt it to know which user to update the password for but I am wondering if there is a better way.

for example: if the user id is 25 I would encrypt 25 to something like f63bfjf7eh3 then send the user an email containing a url such as http://example-domain.com/resetpass.php?code=f63bfjf7eh3 then decrypt that code when they click on the link and update the password to that user id.

sorry if this doesn't make sense I am not very good at explaining.

Comment: @Script47 This would not be on-topic there. There is not code to review. And, the user is asking for help on implementing something, which is also off-topic.

Comment: @SirPython deleted, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f
in PHP you need to make a table, for example tbl_reset_pass

```
with fields id (unique, int(2), primary key and auto incremental), user_id (int(2), foreign key related with user table) and token (varchar)
```

When user asks for reset password, verify that request by email etc...
after you should generate a token, which is encoded string which will be used to send with the link, sending user id encoded is not safe

**so link should be same...**

but in resetpass.php
need to get the code like

```
$code = (!empty($_GET['code'))?base64_decode($_GET['code']):'';
```

then you can use SQL query like...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_reset_pass WHERE token = '$code';
```

to get for which user the reset password is to be done

if result number of rows for above query is exactly 1 then you can redirect your user to change password page.

Don't forgot to use MySQL escape facility in $code before using it in the SQL query as it can contain SQL injection.

When user changes new password, delete the record from tbl_reset_pass

Comment: Token can also be hashed by md5 or sha256, so can't be cracked easily

Comment: would it be ok if I just added a new column to the users table and use it the same way but instead of removing it just set it to null

Comment: It also work that way but in complex projects it's better to use a new table

Answer (score 0):

Make a unique hash using a good algorithm, such as SHA256.  Needs to be unique, and unpredictable. Can use things like microtime(true), existing password hash (it is hashed right?).  It is also good to have password reset